# Powershell constraint violation

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Function Set-SpnPermission {
    param(
        [adsi]$TargetObject,
        [Security.Principal.IdentityReference]$Identity,
        [switch]$Write,
        [switch]$Read
    )
    if(!$write -and !$read){
        throw "Missing either -read or -write"
    }
    $rootDSE = [adsi]"LDAP://RootDSE"
    $schemaDN = $rootDSE.psbase.properties["schemaNamingContext"][0]
    $spnDN = "LDAP://CN=Service-Principal-Name,$schemaDN"
    $spnEntry = [adsi]$spnDN
    $guidArg=@("")
    $guidArg[0]=$spnEntry.psbase.Properties["schemaIDGUID"][0]
    $spnSecGuid = new-object GUID $guidArg

    if($read ){$adRight=[DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]"ReadProperty" }
    if($write){$adRight=[DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]"WriteProperty"}
    if($write -and $read){$adRight=[DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]"readproperty,writeproperty"}
    $accessRuleArgs = $identity,$adRight,"Allow",$spnSecGuid,"None"
    $spnAce = new-object DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $accessRuleArgs
    $TargetObject.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($spnAce)
    $TargetObject.psbase.CommitChanges()    
    return $spnAce
}
```

I am running the above powershell but iam getting an error

> exception calling commitchanges with 0 argument(s) a constraint
> violation occurred

Comment: im unable to replicate, either you're passing wrong arguments to your function or this is a permission issue

Comment: what is the object type of `$TargetObject` when you have this error? does it happen with any object? are you an administrator of your domain or an owner of the object you are looking to update? what are the arguments you're passing to the function when you have this error?

Comment: TargetObject = "LDAP://CN=User,OU=My User Org,DC=domain,DC=net"
$Identity = [security.principal.ntaccount]"domain\user"

Set-SpnPermission -TargetObject $TargetObject -Identity $Identity -write -read . Here is the $TargetObject and I am the administrator of that domain

Comment: Works fine for me with a test user. Did you try adding `$TargetObject.psbase.Options.SecurityMasks = [System.DirectoryServices.SecurityMasks]::Dacl` as shown here? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7855fb7-99e9-43fe-9852-93e97011df5f/adsicomitchanges-a-constraint-violation-occurred?forum=winserverpowershell